# Ignore [DataMember(Name = "xx")] at json serialisation

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

i'm trying to serialize a class which has multiple properties with DataMember attribute. Like this:

```
[DataMember(Name = "F")]
public string FontFamily { get; set; }
```

If i serialize my object the name FontFamily was replaced by the name F:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)
```

results in

```
\"F\":\"Arial\"
```

How can i force NewtonSoft Json to ignore the DataMember attribute and use the original name?

```
\"FontFamily\":\"Arial\"
```

I have no source code access to change the DataMember attribute.

Comment: Without access to the source class that you are serializing, you'd probably have to write a custom `JsonConverter`.